# Decrypting a string using DES-ECB in Rust

Tags: rust, encryption, openssl, des

I'm trying to decrypt a string using the `DES-ECB` encryption algorithm in Rust. I have the following encrypted string:

```
ID2ieOjCrwfgWvL5sXl4B1ImC5QfbsDyzIPKrPZsLT6XiYvvt4HzTf4FNdlY3djNa2mCXTFAkYtwZjohCZ6rhxw7tS9a8Gtq
```

The key is `38346591`. I'm attempting to use the Rust OpenSSL crate for this purpose.

Here's the code I've tried:

```rust
use base64::{engine::general_purpose, Engine as _};
use openssl::error::ErrorStack;
use openssl::symm::{decrypt, Cipher};

fn main() -> Result<(), ErrorStack> {
    let key = b"38346591";
    let encrypted_data_b64 = b"ID2ieOjCrwfgWvL5sXl4B1ImC5QfbsDyzIPKrPZsLT6XiYvvt4HzTf4FNdlY3djNa2mCXTFAkYtwZjohCZ6rhxw7tS9a8Gtq";

    let encrypted_data = general_purpose::STANDARD
        .decode(&encrypted_data_b64)
        .unwrap();

    let cipher = Cipher::des_ecb();
    let decrypted = decrypt(cipher, key, None, &encrypted_data)?;
    println!(
        "Decrypted Data: {:?}",
        String::from_utf8(decrypted).unwrap()
    );

    Ok(())
}
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
[Error { code: 50856204, library: "digital envelope routines", function: "inner_evp_generic_fetch", reason: "unsupported", file: "crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c", line: 341, data: "Global default library context, Algorithm (DES-ECB : 17), Properties ()" }]
```

Additionally, I've also tried using the decrypt function from the OpenSSL crate for this purpose, but it didn't work either.

It seems like `DES-ECB` is not supported or there's something wrong with my approach. Can anyone help me figure out how to properly decrypt this string using DES-ECB in Rust? Any guidance or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT**: The code runs fine on Rust Playground ([gist link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0e7273c6ad222f10d6c86f7a303aba7b)), but throws the error on my Arch machine.

Comment: The ECB mode does not use an IV.

Comment: DES is considered legacy. You need to load OpenSSL's legacy provider to be able to use it. See https://docs.rs/openssl/latest/openssl/provider/struct.Provider.html#method.try_load, https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man7/OSSL_PROVIDER-legacy.html and https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/OSSL_PROVIDER_try_load.html

Comment: The ciphertext must be Base64 decoded, padding must not be disabled, s. online: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0e7273c6ad222f10d6c86f7a303aba7b

Comment: @topaco Thank you for your quick response and for sharing the Rust Playground link. I really appreciate your effort to help with this issue. I've tested the provided code on the Rust Playground, and it indeed works as expected, which is quite puzzling as the same exact code throws the same error on my Arch machine.

Comment: It works on playground because the openssl version on playground is `OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020` but, probably you are using `openssl3` on your machine, and that is why it fails because of @MattCaswell's comment. DES_CBC, DES_ECB are legacy and they, are deprecated in openssl3. You need to use the legacy provider.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code on my local m2 machine, I get the same error:

```
Error: ErrorStack([Error { code: 50856204, library: "digital envelope routines", function: "inner_evp_generic_fetch", reason: "unsupported", file: "crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c", line: 355, data: "Global default library context, Algorithm (DES-ECB : 52), Properties ()" }])
```

The reason is that since crate version "0.10.." the `openssl` crate has switched to `OpenSSL3`, which has marked old and weak algorithms as depreacated and doesn't support them by default anymore.

So, first of all you need to make sure that your OpenSsl installation which is linked to and used by your app has been built with `legacy` support.

And then you need to load the legacy provider (as the default one). Then the above code will work. To achieve it, here is the updated source code:

```rust
    use base64::{Engine as _, engine::general_purpose};
    use openssl::error::ErrorStack;
    use openssl::provider::Provider;
    use openssl::symm::{Cipher, decrypt};
    
    fn main() -> Result<(), ErrorStack> {
      let provider = Provider::try_load(None, "legacy", true).unwrap();
      let key = b"38346591";
      let encrypted_data_b64 = b"ID2ieOjCrwfgWvL5sXl4B1ImC5QfbsDyzIPKrPZsLT6XiYvvt4HzTf4FNdlY3djNa2mCXTFAkYtwZjohCZ6rhxw7tS9a8Gtq";
    
      let encrypted_data = general_purpose::STANDARD
        .decode(&encrypted_data_b64)
        .unwrap();
    
      let cipher = Cipher::des_ecb();
      let decrypted = decrypt(cipher, key, None, &encrypted_data)?;
      println!(
        "Decrypted Data: {:?}",
        String::from_utf8(decrypted).unwrap()
      );
    
      Ok(())
    }
```

Please notice the addition of the `legacy` Provider to the `default` context (i.e. `None`).